# NgIf all objects in an array match a condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I have a structure like so:

```html
{
    documentGroup: {
        Id: 000
        Children: [
            {
                Id: 000
                Status: 1
            },
            {
                Id: 000
                Status: 2
            },...
        ]
    },
},
```

Is there a way to write an ngIf statement to check if all Children elements have `Status == 1`?

EDIT:
When I try this

```
documentGroup.children.every(({status}) => status === 1)
```

I get the error:

> Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 41 in [documentGroup.children.every(({status}) => status === 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need add a new function into your component's `.ts` file which would do the check for you and you can then reference it in the template as follows (`documentsObj` is the object that contains the object in your example):

`.ts`:

```
isAllStatusOne(): boolean {
    return this.documentsObj.documentGroup.Children.every(({Status}) => Status === 1);
}
```

`.html`:

```
*ngIf="isAllStatusOne()"
```

The above code should trigger change detection at the start and any time a property value changes in the `documentsObj` object which should then proceed to check if all `Children` have a `Status` property that is 1. If they all are 1 - `every` should return `true` and the nested elements/components should be rendered.

Alternatively you can use `find` which when using with `Status !== 1` condition would return `undefined` when all Status properties are 1, hence coupled with `!` at the start it will result in `true`:

```
isAllStatusOne(): boolean {
    return !this.documentsObj.documentGroup.Children.find(({Status}) => Status !== 1);
}
```

Comment: I get this error ```Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 43 in [documentGroup.children.every(({ status }) => status === DocumentStatusEnum.ToConfirm)]```

Comment: Hi, it appears that there are issues when there are expressions or function declarations inside the *ngIf directive, I have updated my answer, does this help?

Answer (score 1):

you could also make use of an angular pipe, to check the status and return something else instead (in your case, you could check the status and return true or false).
[Transforming Data Using Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)